# Valor del input radio a un text input

Tags: javascript, html

1. Hay una manera de guardar el valor de mi `radio button` en un `text input` después de que presione el botón? he intentado pero al momento en que presiono el botón el `input text` desaparece y aparece el texto plano.
2. Hay una manera de mostrar automáticamente en un `input text` el valor del `radio button` al ser presionado?

Cualquier respuesta de las dos preguntas me ayudaría mucho.

Este es el código que estoy usando, gracias de antemano.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>javascript - Obtain the value of a radio button</title>
    <script>
        function capturar() {
            var resultado = "ninguno";

            var porNombre = document.getElementsByName("deacuerdo");
            // Recorremos todos los valores del radio button para encontrar el
            // seleccionado
            for (var i = 0; i < porNombre.length; i++) {
                if (porNombre[i].checked)
                    resultado = porNombre[i].value;
            }

            document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = " \
            Por Nombre: "+ resultado;
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Obtain the value of a radio button</h1>
    <form id="form1">

        <p>Deacuerdo: Si<input type="radio" name="deacuerdo" value="si"> No<input type="radio" name="deacuerdo"
                value="no"></p>

    </form>
    <input type="button" value="What is the value of the radio button" onclick="capturar()">
    <div id="resultado"><input type="text"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hola amigo, puedes utilizar JQuery en este proyecto?

Comment: Si, no tendría problema. Pero como se podría hacer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El error es que estás sobre-escribiendo lo que hay en el div con id `resultado` por este motivo desaparece su input, tendrías que agregarle `id` a tu input tipo `text` para que dentro de éste le agregues el valor mediante `.value`.
Te agrego comentarios en el código para su mayor entendimiento. :)

```js
function capturar() {
            var resultado = "ninguno";

            var porNombre = document.getElementsByName("deacuerdo");
            // Recorremos todos los valores del radio button para encontrar el
            // seleccionado
            for (var i = 0; i < porNombre.length; i++) {
                if (porNombre[i].checked)
                    resultado = porNombre[i].value;
            }

            document.getElementById("rInput").value = " \
            Por Nombre: "+ resultado;
        }
        
        //esperamos a que cargue el DOM
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){


  //seleccionamos los inputs tipo radio, recuerda que 
  //esto te trae un HTMLCollections, así que lo tienes que recorrer con un for
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

  //console.log(inputs[0]);

//cremos el for
 for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
  //le agregamos a cada iteración un addEventListener de tipo change
  //como su nombre lo indica al momento de cambiar de input tomará su valor
  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
    //Validamos que ese input tenga el atributo checked
        if(this.checked){
  //si es así obtenemos su valor y lo agregamos al input.
           document.getElementById("rInput").value = this.value;
        }

     }) 


     })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>javascript - Obtain the value of a radio button</title>
    <script>
        
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Obtain the value of a radio button</h1>
    <form id="form1">

        <p>Deacuerdo: Si<input type="radio" name="deacuerdo" value="si"> No<input type="radio" name="deacuerdo"
                value="no"></p>

    </form>
    <input type="button" value="What is the value of the radio button" onclick="capturar()">
    <div id="resultado"><input id="rInput" type="text"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Disculpe la molestia, pero sabe como podría hacer que al presionar el botón se muestre el valor en el input text sin necesidad de presionar un boton?

Comment: Igual su respuesta me sirvio de mucho, gracias.

Comment: Ya quedo editado para que al seleccionar el input tipo `radio` se visualice su valor en el `text`, y de nada un gusto! :)